# Rails has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, redis

I'm trying to create a point of sale app in rails

Right now I have an items model. The items model contains each of the different items carried by the store.

Now I want to create a Orders model. The idea is that this model would contain the items and their quantity for each order. I would be able to view the history of orders to generate analytics etc.

What is the right way to do this?

has_many :through ?
Redis sets?
Other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach is to use an OrderLine model. This is where you would store the quantity of each item ordered.

```
class Order
  has_many :order_lines
  has_many :items, :through => :order_lines
end

class OrderLine
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: Thanks. Do I need a migration and/or attr_accessible variables on orderline?

Comment: You'll need a migration to create the OrderLine model. Note that it should in a separate file to the Order class, I just combined them above for convenience. As for attr_accessible, it depends how you write the controller code.

Comment: Do you know of a more complete tutorial on this? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: This is just basic Rails. The OrderLine model is an example of a many-to-many relationship. Try http://guides.rubyonrails.org/